# MySQL - Unknow Column in field list

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to produce a report that shows the age of computer.

```
SELECT 
M.NAME AS MACHINE_NAME, 
M.CS_MODEL AS MODEL, 
DA.SERVICE_TAG, 
DA.SHIP_DATE,
M.USER_LOGGED AS LAST_LOGGED_IN_USER, 
DW.SERVICE_LEVEL_CODE, 
DW.SERVICE_LEVEL_DESCRIPTION, 
DW.END_DATE AS EXPIRATION_DATE 
FROM MACHINE M 
JOIN DELL_ASSET DA ON (M.BIOS_SERIAL_NUMBER = DA.PARENT_SERVICE_TAG OR M.BIOS_SERIAL_NUMBER = DA.SERVICE_TAG) 
JOIN (SELECT SERVICE_TAG, SERVICE_LEVEL_CODE, SERVICE_LEVEL_DESCRIPTION, MAX(END_DATE) from DELL_WARRANTY group by SERVICE_TAG, SERVICE_LEVEL_CODE, SERVICE_LEVEL_DESCRIPTION) DW ON DW.SERVICE_TAG = DA.SERVICE_TAG 
WHERE M.CS_MANUFACTURER LIKE '%dell%' 
AND M.BIOS_SERIAL_NUMBER!='' 
AND DA.DISABLED != 1 
AND DW.END_DATE < NOW()
AND DW.SERVICE_TAG IS NULL
;
```

The code above produces this error.  What am I doing wrong?

> Blockquote

Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'DW.END_DATE' in 'field list'

Comment: Note that "WHERE M.CS_MANUFACTURER LIKE '%dell%'" cannot use an index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an alias in your sub-query for the `MAX(END_DATE)` calculated field.

```
JOIN (SELECT    SERVICE_TAG
                , SERVICE_LEVEL_CODE
                , SERVICE_LEVEL_DESCRIPTION
                , MAX(END_DATE) AS END_DATE
        from    DELL_WARRANTY 
        group by
                SERVICE_TAG
                , SERVICE_LEVEL_CODE
                , SERVICE_LEVEL_DESCRIPTION) DW 
ON  DW.SERVICE_TAG = DA.SERVICE_TAG
```

Comment: This worked.  The suggestion from @user1281385 worked as well.

Answer (score 1):

you should use

```
MAX(END_DATE) as END_DATE
```

when you define it